# How a shared link is copied automatically in TextField( ) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, textfield, share-intent, texteditingcontroller

So I'm making an app where I want to share youtube links using my app as a post.
I've done the receive-share-intent correctly but the youtube link which I get, I want it to get stored in a TextField.
For example - When we share a youtube link with Whatsapp/ Discord it gets stored in some kind of TextField on those apps. Just like that [This youtube link gets copied here automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM6Ve.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use flutter package called "Shared Plus", just read the docs in following [link](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) and you will understand how it work

Comment: This plugin is used to share something from my Flutter App to other app. I want the reverse of it ; Youtube link to my Flutter App

Comment: Ok then if you did the receive_share_intent correctly please make sure that the textFieldController.text = data.toString(), if it doesn't work please share your code to see it.